# Convert table into complex array php

Tags: php, arrays

This is generated through php(just an example. Can be bigger than this.) How do I put this in only one array? So, that i can pass it to view and output in same format.

```
Name: abc       Address: xyz
Title   Paid
ABC     $100
CDE     $200

Name: rrt       Address: adf
Title   Paid
VDF     $140
CEE     $400

Name: xcv       Address: fdfs
Title   Paid
RET     $120
SSD     $430
```

Comment: And how did you generated this

Comment: It is created in a nested foreach loop. I am trying to convert a pre-existing code which is written in one file(in codeigniter) into mvc format. This is written in codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$output = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'abc',
        'address'=>'xyz',
        'data'=>array(
            array(
                'title'=>ABC,
                'paid'=>100
            ),
            array(
                'title'=>CDE,
                'paid'=>200
            )
        )
    )
);
```